# Reading comma separated text file in spark 1.6

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file which is similar to below

```
20190920

123456789,6325,NN5555,123,4635,890,C,9

985632465,6467,KK6666,654,9780,636,B,8

258063464,6754,MM777,789,9461,895,N,5
```

And I am using spark 1.6 with scala to read this text file

```scala
val df = sqlcontext.read.option("com.databricks.spark.csv")
              .option("header","false").option("inferSchema","false").load(path)

df.show()
```

When I used above command to read it is reading only first column. Is there anything to add to read that file with all column values.

Output I got :

```
20190920

123456789

985632465

258063464

3
```

Comment: The problem is that the first line only has a single column. How do you want to treat that?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should provide schema,So your code will look like this

```
val mySchema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("col1", StringType, true),
    StructField("col2", StringType, true),
    // and other columns ...
  )
)

val df = sqlcontext.read
.schema(mySchema)
.option("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header","false")
.option("inferSchema","false")
.load(path)
```

Comment: It's is giving nulls,  if I want the entire file in one column

Comment: you mean entire row in one column? in this case just use

`val df = spark.read.text(path)`, that's all

Comment: Yes entire row in one column does  spark.read.text works in 1.6?

Comment: other option, you can do it with rdd and then convert to df:
`val struct = StructType(List(StructField("value", StringType, true)))
  val rdd = sc.textFile(path).map(s=>RowFactory.create(s))
  val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,struct)`

Comment: Can we do directly using data bricks csv option